# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I'm having a very strange issue with a dictionary project. Basically I get an access violation error:

0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

It fails when i try to enter a word- in this line:

```
cin >> wrd;
```

This is my code:

```
void Menu::InsertWord(){

cout << "Please enter number of words: " << endl;
int numberOFwords = InsertNum();  //Function that gets a number of words from the user.

Definition* word = new Definition[numberOFwords];
String wrd;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOFwords; i++){

    cout << "Please enter a word: " << endl;
    cin >> wrd;
```

i think it's in the "String" class:

```
#include "String.h"

String::String(char* str) : string(str){
    if (!string)
        size = 0;
    else{
        size = Strlen(str);                     
    string = Strcpy(str, size);        
    }
}

String::String(const String& str){     //copy constractor.

    size = Strlen(str.string);        
    string = Strcpy(str.string, size); //return a pointer to a string.
}

String::~String(){
    if (string)
        delete[] string;
}

String& String::operator=(const String& other){
    if (this != &other && other.string){
        size = other.size;
        if (string)
            delete[] string;
        string = new char[Strlen(other.string) + 1];
        string = Strcpy(other.string, size);
    }
    else if (!string && other.string){
        size = 0;
        delete[] string;
        string = NULL;
    }
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator=(const char* str){
    if (str){  //str ISN'T NULL
        size = Strlen(str);
        delete[] string;
        string = new char[size + 1];
        Strcpy(string, size);
    }
    else if (!string && str){
        size = 0;
        delete[] string;
        string = NULL;
    }
    return *this;
}

bool String::operator==(const String& other) const{
    if (size != other.size)
        return FALSE;
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (string[i] != other.string[i])
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool String::operator!=(const String& other) const{
    return (!(*this == other));
}

istream& operator >>(istream& is, String& other) {

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size || i <= WORD_SIZE ; i++){
        is >> other.string[i];
        if (i == WORD_SIZE)
            other.string[WORD_SIZE] = '\0';
    }
    return is;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const String& other) {

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size; i++)
        os << other.string[i];
    return os;
}

String& String::operator -=(const char& chr) {
    RemoveChar(chr);
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator +=(const char& chr) {
    AddChar(chr);
    return *this;
}

void String::PrintString(){

    size = Strlen(string);           

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){  
        cout << string[i];            //print the current char.
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void String::AddChar(const char& chr){

    char* temp = new char[size + 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = string[i];
    temp[size] = chr;
    temp[size + 1] = '\0';

    delete[] string;
    string = temp;
    size = size + 1;

}

void String::RemoveChar(const char& chr){
    int j, i = 0,counter = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++){
        if (chr == string[i])
            counter++;
    }
    char* temp = new char[(size - counter) + 1];
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < size; j++, i++){
        if (string[i] != chr)
            temp[j] = string[i];
        else
            j--;
    }
    temp[size - counter] = '\0';
    string = temp;
}

char& String::operator[] (int index){

    if (index >= 0 && index < size){
        for (index = 0; string[index] != '\0'; index++);
        return string[index];
    }
    return string[0];
}

int String::Strlen(const char* str){
    if (str){
        int counter = 0;                                  
        for (; counter < size; counter++);                
        return counter;                                   
    }
    return 0;
}

char* String::Strcpy(const char* str, int size){

    char* TempString = new char[size + 1];

    if (!TempString){                      //check if memory allocate.
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){        //copy the string char by char.
        TempString[i] = str[i];

        if (i + 1 == size)                 //if it's the end of the string
            TempString[size] = '\0';       //enter '\0' at the end.
    }
    return TempString;                     //return char pointer to the string.
}
```

Comment: `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000` You are dereferenceing a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in ``istream& operator >>(istream& is, String& other)`` and look at the ``other`` parameters state.

Comment: You read characters as long as `i < other.size || i <= WORD_SIZE` is true. That can't be right. Especially the `||`

Comment: Please also note that `Definition* word = new Definition[numberOFwords];` does NOT create any objects, but only references.

Answer (score 3):

You did not show the default constructor of class String but I am sure if it exists it sets data member string to NULL or nullptr.

```
String wrd;
```

So when you use operator >>

```
cin >> wrd;
```

you are trying to access memory that was not allocated by the object of the class.

Also I think this condition in the loop statement of the operator >>

```
istream& operator >>(istream& is, String& other) {

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size || i <= WORD_SIZE ; i++){
                                   ^^
```

is wrong.

It seems there shall be at least like

```
istream& operator >>(istream& is, String& other) {

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size && i <= WORD_SIZE ; i++){
                                   ^^
```

Also I suspect that in this copy constructor

```
String::String(const String& str){     //copy constractor.

    size = Strlen(str.string);        
    string = Strcpy(str.string, size); //return a pointer to a string.
}
```

there should be

```
    size = str.size;
```

instead of

```
    size = Strlen(str.string);
```

because str.string is not zero terminated.

And it is totally unclear how function `Strcpy` works; whether it allocates dynamically a memory for the copy of a string or not.

Compare the constructor

```
String::String(char* str) : string(str){
    if (!string)
        size = 0;
    else{
        size = Strlen(str);                     
    string = Strcpy(str, size);        
    }
}
```

with for example this assignment operator (that by the way in any case is wrong; for example what is the meaning of condition else if (!string && str){ ?)

```
String& String::operator=(const char* str){
    if (str){  //str ISN'T NULL
        size = Strlen(str);
        delete[] string;
        string = new char[size + 1];
        Strcpy(string, size);
    }
    else if (!string && str){
        size = 0;
        delete[] string;
        string = NULL;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

In the construtor you do not explicitly allocate memory while in the assignment operator you explicitly allocate memory. So it looks at least very strange.:)